# AppEngine - very slow deployments, "cache" step

Tags: google-app-engine

I was experiencing very slow AppEngine deployments, but thought that it's just normal for bigger apps. However, recently I started deploying the exact same code to a different service - and that was much faster. I started to investaigate what makes my builds so slow. I came upon these few lines that are the last lines in my build logs:

```
Timer: Cache started at 2024-01-27T04:21:17Z
Reusing cache layer 'google.go.runtime:go'
Adding cache layer 'google.go.gomod:gopath'
Timer: Cache ran for 12m33.274573409s and ended at 2024-01-27T04:33:50Z
```

Unfortunately, even though a lot of people complain about slow deployment times, these lines are ungooglable. The time it takes to build the complete image ranges from 9 to 20 minutes, and it seems it's always this step that takes the longest.

Here are the same lines from the second (fast) service:

```
Timer: Cache started at 2024-02-18T07:53:16Z
Reusing cache layer 'google.go.runtime:go'
Reusing cache layer 'google.go.gomod:gopath'
Timer: Cache ran for 5.779188003s and ended at 2024-02-18T07:53:21Z
```

We see that it's  "reusing" a cache layer. Here is a fast build that is "adding" the layer:

```
Timer: Cache started at 2024-02-16T07:46:41Z
Reusing cache layer 'google.go.runtime:go'
Adding cache layer 'google.go.gomod:gopath'
Timer: Cache ran for 49.666733225s and ended at 2024-02-16T07:47:31Z
```

What is this "Cache" that is "ran", and what makes it so slow?

The services differ only in that one has static_dir handlers. I tried removing them from the first one, but it was still slow.

Comment: Are you using `cloud shell` to deploy app or local terminal? If you are not using `cloud shell`, can try deploy using it?

Comment: I use `gcloud app deploy`

Comment: I meant to ask whether you are using Cloud Shell or VS code terminal or other terminals. because, Deploying through the [cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/deploy-app-engine-app)

involves a health check on the service as well and will return errors to help us further diagnose the problems here.

Comment: I deployed using Cloud Shell. It was just as slow - 11m7s. The "Updating service [default]" step took most of that time.

Comment: Can you share logs by re-deploying by using command `gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug.`

Comment: For some reason if I redirect output to a file, gcloud exits immediately with no output. But I can tell, that it spends the most time doing this:

Updating service [default]..._DEBUG: Operation [apps/xxx/operations/72a00929-5f6d-41b5-a604-36af5d73d14b] not complete. Waiting to retry.